# How to add a Facebook share box to a page?

Tags: facebook, button, share

I saw many similar questions here but their answers don't work for me by some reasons.
I need the share box, not the like one.
Can anyone share a working solution?

Thank you very much

**EDIT**

The only working way I found is to add a link like:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.mysite.com&t=Title" target="blank">Share on Facebook</a>
```

But in this case there is no counter and I need it. Is there a way to do it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it here: http://www.simplebloggertutorials.com/2010/05/how-to-add-facebook-share-button-with.html

Just need to add following code:

```
<div>
   <a name="fb_share" type="box_count" expr:share_url="data:post.url" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

very easy solution and according to the [link](https://www.hs.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150211527410844) provided by Jarede Facebook will support Share button in the future.

Comment: Careful with this, this is the same as Facebook Markup Language (FBML) witch Facebook already mention it a deprecated markup and you should use Javascript API, Graph API and/or the Social plugins! the `sharer.php` could be gone any minute and you will end up trying to find other solution. This is not a correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

Much more nicer solution here: [Facebook Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Answer (score 0):

The share button has been deprecated in preference for the Like button.  Probably best to keep up with the rest of the world and use Like instead of trying to implement the outdated Share.

I found this:

https://www.hs.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150211527410844

Comment: Share box with a counter still works on thousands of sites and blogs. It is much better from marketing point of view so we want it. Thanks for advice anyway.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link, even though the solution from there is not working I found another one.